# Как к объекту применить одно и тоже свойство CSS несколько раз?

Tags: css

Мне нужно сделать текст такой же.

[image: Скриншот]

Проблема в том, что когда я сделал эту белую окраску на внешней стороне текста, я не могу добавить тень текста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как решить эту ситуацию?

```css
BODY{
    background-color: #76a6ff;
}
p{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px white;
}
```

Comment: Я же не могу 2 раза использовать свойство "text-shadow"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внезапно, через запятую можно вставлять несколько теней.

```css
BODY{
    background-color: #76a6ff;
}
p{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px white,
                 0px 10px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<p>Я изучил обучающие материалы к лабораторной работе</p>
```

[text-shadow | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)